# Google Analytics Custom Dimensions Recording Wrong Data

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We've got GA4 and UA set up for a WP site using Monster Insights. The code to connect GTM to the WP site is in the code; however, everything else is through GA and the Monster Insights plugin.

In April last year, the data for post author custom dimension within UA had begun slowly declining in count, hitting zero early June. The code did not change, nor did any of the GA settings from what I can tell.

Considering UA is being sunset, I'm moving the custom dimension over to the GA4 tag. Logging dataLayer shows the pagePostAuthor is setting correctly, alongside the URL and post title etc.; however, within the pages and screens dashboard on GA, the pagePostAuthor column shows the post title.

If the dataLayer has the right info, what's the disconnect between the dataLayer and the custom dimension's data set?

Answer (score 0):

You usually map your DL values to analytics dimensions through GTM. Therefore, it's likely that GTM's mapping is off.

On the other hand, if you didn't set up your GTM, then it may be that the data is being tracked without GTM, even if you've loaded the GTM script. The extension may just use gtag directly, taking the data from the DL, which will make the debugging much more tedious, so I'd suggest looking at GTM making sure it's being used.

Comment: If it _is_ taking data from the DL, why does the DL show the correct data for pagePostAuthor but GA shows differently?

Comment: Usually third parties don't touch DL. DL is being used by GTM. Try blocking GTM from loading and inspect Network hits to Google's `?collect` endpoint. You don't need to open GA to debug it. You use your Network tab instead.

Comment: Oooooh that's super helpful, thanks! It isn't showing the cd in the headers, so I'm working with the site owner to get write access to GTM.